# Tkinter: Update variable in next frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day StackOverFlow!

I need to update var in next frame, using tkinter after it's was changed.
It's work, if i put code on "Page2" in function. BUT.

Can somebody advice please about this?

p.s. I apologize for the code not being clean enough.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

#Main frame

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
     
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         
        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        self.geometry("450x350")
        self.title('tool')
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
  
        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {} 
  
        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, 
                  Page2,):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
  
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
#class

class Pages:
    global timeStamp
    timeStamp = 0

#start page

class StartPage(tk.Frame, Pages):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def TimeFocusIn(event):
                timeStampInput.delete(0,"end")

        timeInputName = ttk.Label(self, 
                              text = "Enter Time in HHMMSS format:")
        timeStampInput = ttk.Entry(self)
        timeStampInput.insert(0, "HHMMSS")
        timeStampInput.bind("<FocusIn>", TimeFocusIn)

 #Save time button
        
        def SaveTime(**kwargs):
            global timeStamp
            var = StringVar()
            timeVarOut = timeStampInput.get()
            var.set(timeVarOut)
            timeVarOutTxt = ttk.Label(self, text=f'{timeVarOut}')
            timeVarOutTxt.grid(row = 7, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)  
            timeStamp = timeVarOut

        saveTimeInputButt = ttk.Button(self, 
                                       text = "Save time", command = SaveTime)

        timeVarText = ttk.Label(self, 
                              text = "TimeStamp is:")
        
        buttPage2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Next page",
                                  command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))

#Grid placing

        timeInputName.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky ="nsew")
        timeStampInput.grid(row = 5, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky ="nsew")
        saveTimeInputButt.grid(row = 5, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky ="nsew")
        buttPage2.grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        timeVarText.grid(row = 7, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

#Page 2

class Page2(tk.Frame, Pages):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Next page")
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        timeVarOutTxt = ttk.Label(self, text=f'Timestamp is: {timeStamp}')
        timeVarOutTxt.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)  

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Back",
                             command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

# Run GUI

app = tkinterApp()

def message():
    app.update()
    print(timeStamp)
    app.after(20, message) 

app.after(20, message)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the markup of your code, it's hard to read.

Comment: to format code you have to use ``` instead of ''' . Or select code and use `Ctrl+K`

Comment: if code works when you put in function then what is the problem? Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. And what variable do you want to update? We can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: every frame has `self.parent` to access `tkinterApp` and it has `self.frames` to access every frame - so in every frame could work `self.parent.frames[Page2]`

Comment: don't use `global timeStamp` but create `self.timeStamp` in `__init__`

Comment: viewing of code fixing. sorry about this.

want update var "timeStamp".
it's saving value on startpage. save it in memory, but don't execute at label at Page2

Comment: it seems you fixed it in wrong way because you keep `#comments` in first column and it looks like many separated scripts. You should select all code and use `Ctrl+K` . information about `timeStamp` add in question - other people will see it, so more people may help you.

Comment: classes and label are created at start of program but you change value in `timeStamp` later - you have to change text in label on your own. And this need to keep label with `self.` - `self.timeVarOutTxt` - to have access to this label in other functions and outside class.

Comment: if you want share value `timeStamp` between classes then better create it inside `tkinterApp`. Creating class `Pages` with `timeStamp` is useless.

Comment: you would havet to use `textvariable=timeStamp` (without `.get()`) in label to update label automatically when you change value in `timeStamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share data between Frames then you could keep it in `tkinterApp` as `self.timeStamp` and then every page will have access using `controller.timeStamp`

if you want to access it in some function then keep `self.controller = controller`

---

But this can't change text in label - you have to do it on your own using

You have to use `self.` in `self.timeVarOutTxt` and later in `saveTime` you can access label in other frame and change it.

```
self.controller.frames[Page2].timeVarOutTxt['text'] = f'Timestamp is: {self.controller.timeStamp}'
```

---

Working code with other changes:

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: all classes after imports

# Main frame  # PEP8: one space after `#` 

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
     
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # __init__ function for class Tk
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        #self.geometry("450x350")
        self.title('tool')

        self.time_stamp = 0
        
        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  # PEP8: inside `()` uses `=` without spaces
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
  
        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {} 
  
        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
  
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

        time_input_name = ttk.Label(self, text="Enter Time in HHMMSS format:")
        
        self.time_stamp_input = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.time_stamp_input.insert(0, "HHMMSS")
        self.time_stamp_input.bind("<FocusIn>", self.time_focus_in)

        save_time_input_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Save time", command=self.save_time)

        time_var_text = ttk.Label(self, text="TimeStamp is:")
        
        button_page2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Next page", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Page2))

        time_input_name.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        self.time_stamp_input.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        save_time_input_button.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        button_page2.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        time_var_text.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    def time_focus_in(self, event):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
        self.time_stamp_input.delete(0, "end")

    def save_time(self, **kwargs):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions  
        self.time_var_out_txt = ttk.Label(self, text=self.time_stamp_input.get())
        self.time_var_out_txt.grid(row=7, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.controller.time_stamp = self.time_stamp_input.get()
        self.controller.frames[Page2].time_var_out_txt['text'] = f'Timestamp is: {self.controller.time_stamp}'

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):        
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Next page")
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.time_var_out_txt = ttk.Label(self, text=f'Timestamp is: {controller.time_stamp}')
        self.time_var_out_txt.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)  

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions after classes (before main code)

def message():
    #app.update()  # no need it
    print(app.time_stamp, end='\r')  # print in the same line
    app.after(20, message) 

# --- main ---

# Run GUI

app = tkinterApp()

app.after(20, message)

app.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Other idea: in every Page add function `before_switch()` and execute it

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.before_switch()
        frame.tkraise()
```

and this function in class `Page2` could update label always before displaying `Page2`

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk

# --- classes ---

# Main frame  # PEP8: one space after `#` 

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
     
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # __init__ function for class Tk
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        #self.geometry("450x350")
        self.title('tool')

        self.time_stamp = 0
        
        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  # PEP8: inside `()` uses `=` without spaces
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
  
        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {} 
  
        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.frame = None
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
  
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        if self.frame:
            self.frame.after()
            
        self.frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.frame.before()
        
        self.frame.tkraise()

class Page(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

    def before(self):
        """Run before showing Page."""
        pass
    
    def after(self):
        """Run after showing Page."""
        pass
    
class StartPage(Page):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        time_input_name = ttk.Label(self, text="Enter Time in HHMMSS format:")
        
        self.time_stamp_input = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.time_stamp_input.insert(0, "HHMMSS")
        self.time_stamp_input.bind("<FocusIn>", self.time_focus_in)

        save_time_input_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Save time", command=self.save_time)

        time_var_text = ttk.Label(self, text="TimeStamp is:")
        
        button_page2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Next page", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Page2))

        time_input_name.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        self.time_stamp_input.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        save_time_input_button.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        button_page2.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        time_var_text.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    def time_focus_in(self, event):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
        self.time_stamp_input.delete(0, "end")

    def save_time(self, **kwargs):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions  
        self.time_var_out_txt = ttk.Label(self, text=self.time_stamp_input.get())
        self.time_var_out_txt.grid(row=7, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

    def after(self):
        """Update shared value after showing Page."""
        self.controller.time_stamp = self.time_stamp_input.get()

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):        
        super().__init__(parent, controller)
        
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Next page")
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.time_var_out_txt = ttk.Label(self, text=f'Timestamp is: {controller.time_stamp}')
        self.time_var_out_txt.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)  

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    def before(self):
        """Update label before showing Page."""
        self.time_var_out_txt['text'] = f'Timestamp is: {self.controller.time_stamp}'

# --- functions ---

def message():
    #app.update()  # no need it
    print(app.time_stamp, end='\r')
    app.after(20, message) 

# --- main ---

# Run GUI

app = tkinterApp()

app.after(20, message)

app.mainloop()
```